# Single sign on for PHP and ASP.NET using read cookie

Tags: php, asp.net

I have created an application writing in php language. Now,i need develop new .net application using same login database. What i want is after end user login by the php application and click a link to my .net new application without re-sign in again. Any Idea or suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement WIF on the .net side and SimpleSAML in the PHP solution?  Federated security with the WIF framework using the **SAML** protocol should work.  What's better is SAML is an open standard so a lot of resources out there.

To get you started:

**Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ee748475.aspx
**SimpleSAML** https://simplesamlphp.org/

EDIT:  I'm recommending the above because you cannot share cookies cross domain and you shouldn't really be trying to roll your own security where possible. You can also look at OAuth2 http://openid.net/connect/.

It seems WIF can also support OAuth2 with extensions https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alikl/2011/03/03/running-windows-identity-foundation-wif-extensions-for-oauth-2-0-sample/

Comment: I have a separate php site.Now,I have an existing asp.net application I wish to create a single SignOn which will work for both the php site and also asp.net application. 
The actual aim is the user of the php site can use the asp.net application. So i have a php site,ASP.NET Website which needs to work together.
 The useername and password will be entered in an php site and should be send to .aspx page for login also the user is looged in the asp.net website.
 After logging in if the user clicks or goto the php site he should be already logged and should not be asked to Login again.

Comment: users login to php site and cookie is created.Asp.net site will read cookie and with login screen

Comment: **If** the sites are cross domain this isn't possible (to share cookies).  I've edited my post above while you were posting, please re-read as it may be an option for you.